# How to update content of the file in Alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco

My java-backed webscript copies file in a repository to a temp folder and edits it for my needs. During its work a new content is generated and it must be written to a created temporary file.

But there is a problem: the first nor the second code below does not updates file's content.

```
ContentWriter contentWriter = this.contentService.getWriter(tempFile,
                               ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
contentWriter.putContent(content);
```

And the second:

```
`
WritableByteChannel byteChannel = contentWriter.getWritableChannel();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(content.getBytes());
byteChannel.write(buffer);
byteChannel.close();
`
```

How to update file's content?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
ContentWriter contentWriter = contentService.getWriter(noderef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
        contentWriter.setMimetype("text/csv");
        FileChannel fileChannel = contentWriter.getFileChannel(false);
        ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(logLine.getBytes());
        try {
            fileChannel.position(contentWriter.getSize());
            fileChannel.write(bf);
            fileChannel.force(false);
            fileChannel.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm appending a line to an existing file, so logLine is the appending string.

Comment: I want to replace the whole content on temp file. Your code does not works for it.

Comment: Hi If you want to replace everything, just don't use the line: fileChannel.position(contentWriter.getSize());
Then it will by default use 0 as starting position.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried to comment that line and to set to zero: fileChannel.position(0). Alfresco Web Client (/alfresco) shows that file was modified (date changes), but its content wasn't.

Comment: Strange it does work for me, are you sure your ByteBuffer is not empty? have you printed out content.getBytes()?

Comment: ByteBuffer is not empty, it is filled by correct data that was changed by the script...